# How to extract the response from ajax call using js?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a ajax call on my function

### js part

```js
_this.ajaxPost(appUrl + "reports/appointment/save", post_str, function(response) {
  var res = eval("(" + response + ")");
  if (!res.error) {
    var data = res.msg;
  } else {
    if (res.status == "error") {
      _this.showPopMsg("error", 'Error when updating db ', res.msg);
    }
  }

}, function(response) {
  alert(response);
  var res = eval("(" + response + ")");
  _this.showPopMsg("error", 'Updating DB', res.msg);
});
```

### php part

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=> false, "status"=>"success", "msg"=>$conditions['reg']->result()));
```

which returns a response like,

```
{"error":false,"status":"success","msg":[{"name":"dreamhunter","mob_num":"9876543210","email":"afl@thnfgd"}]}
```

and I'm trying to extract the **msg** part using **js**, the msg part contains an array like

```
[{"name":"dream hunter","mob_num":"9876543210","email":"afl@thnfgd"}]
```

and here name,mob-num and email are keys and I'm trying to extract their values

I have tried

```
var res = eval("(" + response + ")");
var data = res.msg;
alert(data[name]);//which is the first key
```

which is not working. How can I extract this?

Comment: Never use `eval` to parse JSON

Comment: Why do you use `eval` on the response? That is very dangerous. Imagine embedded functions with unknown side-effects in the response that will execute on `eval`

Comment: try data[0]["name"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the following response:

```
var x = '{"error":false,"status":"success","msg":[{"name":"dreamhunter","mob_num":"9876543210","email":"afl@thnfgd"}]}'
```

Using [**JSON.Parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can extract the object:

```
var y = JSON.parse(x);
```

Now you have an object like this:

```
{
    error:false,
    msg: [{
        email: "afl@thnfgd"
        mob_num: "9876543210"
        name: "dreamhunter"
    }],
    status:"success"
}
```

To access the properties, such as the `email` for example, of the first message you can do this:

```
console.log(y.msg[0].email);
```

```js
var x = '{"error":false,"status":"success","msg":[{"name":"dreamhunter","mob_num":"9876543210","email":"afl@thnfgd"}]}'
var y = JSON.parse(x);

console.log('msg[0].email: ', y.msg[0].email);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can view the data using :-

```
alert(data[0].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSON object methods to handle JSON in javascript.

For instance

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"error":false,"status":"success","msg":[{"name":"dreamhunter","mob_num":"9876543210","email":"afl@thnfgd"}]}')

alert(data.msg[0].name)
```